# Build directory .js files missing, css link broken, jpegs not processing - common issue?

Tags: html, ant, html5boilerplate

I'm running HTML5 Boilerplate 3.0 and the latest ant build script. I'm on Windows 7.

After a few issues, the .bat file now executes and everything runs. Upon completion though the script directory is my *publish* folder is empty, though I have the following .js files in my *intermediate* directory:

- js/scripts-concant.min.js
- js/scipt.js
- js/plugins.js
- js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js
- js/lib/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js

In a possibly related issue, my .css file is minified and renamed and links beautifully from *index.html* but the rest of the files continue to try to link to style.css

In a maybe possibly related issue, I get a can't open  for writing error on every single jpeg that it tries to open. They're copied across fine though, so I just wanted to include this for completion.

I've Googled to no avail and can't seem to find a common reason this would happen. I'd really appreciate any pointers, I don't mind fixing things myself, I just can't find a common thread here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the css issue I was having this issue because I had to include all index files by putting specifying *.html in config/project.properties file.

```
# Web Pages
#
# These are the pages (files) that will be served to users (.html, .php, .asp, etc).
Files in this property will
# be minified / optimised and have any stylesheet or javascript references updated to
the   minified examples
#
# The paths need to be relative 
#
# Files can be added in a comma separated form
file.pages        = *.html
```

Don't know about the other issues

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted the .css issue beautifully, I'm not sure why it doesn't do that by default.